# Intervention can't read exif data but exif_read_data() can

Tags: php, wamp, intervention

$image->exif() returns null while exif_read_data($path) returns all of the info I need. I'd rather use intervention because I wont always have a local file. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the mbstring extension enabled in PHP

Comment: Yes, mbstring is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you have to be dealing with a physical file, not its' contents. So if you do this, it wont work:

```
$image->make(file_get_contents($path));
```

But will if you reference a path:

```
$image->make($path);
```

Hope that helps anyone else running into this issue.

Comment: Could you please have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685885/laravel-storageget-does-not-return-exif-data-of-image

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.8 change

```
Image::make(Storage::get($fl))->exif();
```

with

```
Image::make(Storage::path($fl))->exif();
```