# Laravel Storage::get() does not return exif data of image

Tags: php, image, laravel

I am trying to get the image exif data so that I can use the Image intervention orientate function.

The only problem is that I cant read the exif data using the Storage::get()

First I am storing Uploaded images like this:

```
$filename = uniqid().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = "images/$id/$filename";
Storage::put($path, File::get($file->getRealPath()));
```

The in a queue I am reading the images, doing some resizing and upload to AWS:

```
$image = Image::make(Storage::disk('images')->get("$this->id/$file"));
            $image->orientate();
            $image->resize(null, 600, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $image->stream('jpg', 85);
Storage::put("images/$this->id/main/$file", $image);
$image->destroy();
```

The image does get resized and uploaded to AWS but the only problem is that it will show up sideways, so it seems that I cant read the exif data using:

```
Storage::disk('images')->get("$this->id/$file")
```

I have runned: php -m | more and I can see that "exif" is listed so I have the module in my Laravel Forge DO server

Answer (score 2):

Install `Intervention\Image` by following command.

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Update `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
],
'aliases' => [
    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
]
```

Use Library:

```
$data = Image::make(public_path('IMG.jpg'))->exif();

if (isset($data['GPSLatitude'])) {
    $lat = eval('return ' . $data['GPSLatitude'][0] . ';')
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLatitude'][1] . ';') / 60)
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLatitude'][2] . ';') / 3600);

    $lng = eval('return ' . $data['GPSLongitude'][0] . ';')
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLongitude'][1] . ';') / 60)
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLongitude'][2] . ';') / 3600);

    echo "$lat, $lng";
} else {
    echo "No GPS Info";
}
```

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravelRecent"

config/image.php:
'driver' => 'imagick'

Answer (score 0):

To get the exif data from Image intervention you must run the `exif()` function

It's very simple, just add:

```
$image->exif();
```

The `exif()` function will return all existing data in an array();

You can pass a parameter to the `exif()` function which will bring back some information in a string, for example: `$image->exif('model')`

You can read more about this on the Image [intervention website](http://image.intervention.io/api/exif)

Comment: But is it not enough to just run? ```Image::make('foo.jpg')->orientate();``` 
http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate

Comment: No you have to add the exif() function since it returns an array().

Comment: So you could potentially do Image::make('foo.jpg')->orientate()->exif(); I believe, but not entirely sure.

Comment: It seems that once I store the image I cant read the ```orientate()``` It works if I use eg $request->file() directly

Comment: $request->file() returns an object. file_get_contents($request->file()) returns a string which you pass to the Image::make() function.

Answer (score 0):

Some image manipulation software actually remove meta data. If you have GD installed and do not have metadata, it may not exists. Best way to test this, try another image.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getImageLocation($file)
    {
        try {
            if (is_file($file)) {
                $info = exif_read_data($file);
                if (isset($info['GPSLatitude']) && isset($info['GPSLongitude']) &&
                    isset($info['GPSLatitudeRef']) && isset($info['GPSLongitudeRef']) &&
                    in_array($info['GPSLatitudeRef'], array('E', 'W', 'N', 'S')) && in_array($info['GPSLongitudeRef'], array('E', 'W', 'N', 'S'))) {

                    $GPSLatitudeRef = strtolower(trim($info['GPSLatitudeRef']));
                    $GPSLongitudeRef = strtolower(trim($info['GPSLongitudeRef']));

                    $lat_degrees_a = explode('/', $info['GPSLatitude'][0]);
                    $lat_minutes_a = explode('/', $info['GPSLatitude'][1]);
                    $lat_seconds_a = explode('/', $info['GPSLatitude'][2]);
                    $lng_degrees_a = explode('/', $info['GPSLongitude'][0]);
                    $lng_minutes_a = explode('/', $info['GPSLongitude'][1]);
                    $lng_seconds_a = explode('/', $info['GPSLongitude'][2]);

                    $lat_degrees = $lat_degrees_a[0] / $lat_degrees_a[1];
                    $lat_minutes = $lat_minutes_a[0] / $lat_minutes_a[1];
                    $lat_seconds = $lat_seconds_a[0] / $lat_seconds_a[1];
                    $lng_degrees = $lng_degrees_a[0] / $lng_degrees_a[1];
                    $lng_minutes = $lng_minutes_a[0] / $lng_minutes_a[1];
                    $lng_seconds = $lng_seconds_a[0] / $lng_seconds_a[1];

                    $lat = (float)$lat_degrees + ((($lat_minutes * 60) + ($lat_seconds)) / 3600);
                    $lng = (float)$lng_degrees + ((($lng_minutes * 60) + ($lng_seconds)) / 3600);

                    //If the latitude is South, make it negative.
                    //If the longitude is west, make it negative
                    $GPSLatitudeRef == 's' ? $lat *= -1 : '';
                    $GPSLongitudeRef == 'w' ? $lng *= -1 : '';

                    return ['latitude' => $lat, 'longitude' => $lng];
                }
            }
            return ['latitude' => null, 'longitude' => null];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return ['latitude' => null, 'longitude' => null];
        }
    }
```