# Display the uploaded images at the top of the gallery (Laravel)

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to display the uploaded images at the top of the gallery but i don't know how to do that. There is a simple method which can I use it and which can be add to my code? I'm trying to find a solution because i have a gallery of images and I would like the images that are added to be displayed at the top of the gallery.
There is my controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $images_salons = SalonsImageGallery::get();
    return view('admin-panel.salons.salons', compact('images_salons'));
}
// * Upload image function

   public function upload(Request $request)
   {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image_salons' => 'required',
        'image_salons.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000'
    ]);


    foreach ($request->image_salons as $image) {
        $input['image_salons'] = uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/salons/thumbnails');
        $resize_image = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $resize_image->resize(500, 500, function($constraint){
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath . '/' .  $input['image_salons']);

        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/salons');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $input['image_salons']);

        SalonsImageGallery::create($input);
    }


    return back()
        ->with('success', 'Imaginea/imaginile au fost incarcate cu succes!');
}
```

And this is my view:

```
@if($images_salons->count())

            @foreach($images_salons as $image)

                <div class='box'>
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox"
                       href="/images/salons/{{ $image->image_salons }}">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt=""
                             src="/images/salons/thumbnails/{{ $image->image_salons }}"/>
                    </a>
                    <form action="{{ url('home/saloane',$image->id) }}" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <button type="submit" class="close-icon btn btn-danger">X</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            @endforeach

        @endif
```

Comment: If you write your file name for the image, you could name it  xyz_{current_timestamp}.jpg for example. Than you can sort it by date. Or you get the exif data of each image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685885/laravel-storageget-does-not-return-exif-data-of-image

Comment: Hmm, without sort the images by date is possible to display the uploaded images at the top of the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution!

```
$images_salons = SalonsImageGallery::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This code display my images which are store in database descending!

Comment: Didn’t knew, the image paths stored in database. I thought you are fetching straight from file system.